# Case When and Else statements being evaluated even after finding a true condition

Tags: sql, if-statement, sas, case

Using SAS, I create a global macro variable called Flag that is either 0 or 1 depending on which pathway the code took.  If it's 0, then only table A was created.  If it's 2, A AND B were created.  I then want to create a summary table.  If only A exists, I need the max value of a certain variable from A.  If B exists, I need the max value of the same variable from B, instead of A.  My SQL code looks like this:

```
Proc SQL; create table WANT as 
case
when &flag. = 0 then (select max(var) from A)
when &flag. = 1 then (select max(var) from B)
end as Var2
from HAVE;
```

The problem is I get an error message saying "table B does not exist" when Flag = 0 (which is correct, table B will not exist).  I found numerous [sources](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43352/does-sql-server-case-statement-evaluate-all-conditions-or-exit-on-first-true-con) online that say that it should exit after the first true condition is found.  Figuring that maybe it was evaluating all of the when clauses for some reason, I tried changing it to look like this:

```
Proc SQL; Create table WANT as select
case
when &flag. = 0 then (select max(var) from A)
else (select max(var) from B)
end as Var2;
```

In the above code it shouldn't even be getting to the else statement.  I know for a fact that the variables and comparisons are all resolving correctly because I've tried each of them separately, and it also works fine when flag = 1.  There are any number of work-arounds I could use like dummy tables, global %if-%thens, etc.  I would like to be able to fix the problem within the code, but also to know if I'm understanding how SQL processes their CASE-WHEN statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is too late to modify the code after it has already started running.

Assuming the your macro variable FLAG has an actual value (and not the name of some variable you want to reference) you can use macro logic to conditionally generate the code.

```
proc sql ; 
create table WANT as 
%if  &flag. = 0 %then %do;
 select max(var) from A
%end;
%else %do;
 select max(var) from B
%end;
;
quit;
```

Put it is probably easier if you change your process to put the name of the source dataset into a macro variable instead of setting a value of 0 or 1 into the macro variable.  Then you can just use that macro variable in place of the dataset name in your query.

```
%let sourceds=A;
proc sql ; 
create table WANT as select max(var) from &sourceds;
quit;
```

Comment: The others gave me the clarification I was after, but I think this is probably the best solution, so I'll mark this as solved.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

SAS is correct.  You are confusing *evaluating* the expression with *parsing* the SQL statement.

All tables and columns need to exist during the parsing phase.  This is different from actually evaluating the expressions.

I am not really familiar with a way of doing what you want -- in SAS `proc sql` or in any database.

Comment: I see.  So the code is evaluated twice in a sense?  The first pass parses for errors in syntax or things like missing tables, and then the second pass evaluates the syntax and processes the statements.  Is that correct?  There are definitely solutions to my problem, but they all seemed a little sloppy to me.  I was more curious as to the "why" of the problem, and I think you've answered that.

Comment: Yes, code must be compiled (in the case of PROC SQL, maybe interpreted) before it is execute.  It sounds like you want dynamic SAS code.  As you suggest, one way to do this in SAS is to use the macro language, because when the macro language executes it can decide what SAS code to generate, and then the generated SAS code is compiled and executed.

Comment: Quentin gave me a good idea.  After I create table A, I use `Proc sql; Select Max(Var) into :MaxVar from A`.  Then, if the second path is taken, I just overwrite MaxVar with the value from table B.  Then I just reference that macro variable in my summary table.  No CASE-WHEN-ELSE needed.  Thanks for all the clarification!